# For what numbers $n$ every group of order $n$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> What are the numbers $n$ such that every group of order $n$ is abelian?

1. For every prime $p$, every group of order $p$ or $p^2$ is abelian.
2. If there is a prime $p$ such that $p^3\mid n$, then I can take a direct product of a nonabelian group of order $p^3$ with a cyclic group of order $\frac{n}{p}$ and get a nonabelian group.

So, we are left with values of $n$ divisible by more than one prime, but not divisible by $p^3$ for any prime $p$.

For some orders of this type (i.e. $35$) all are abelian, but not for all ofcourse.

Comment: @TimRatigan: No, for example, $D_4$, or $Q_8$, or the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  For some reason I was thinking about non-trivial centers.